# ionic platform add android results in the following error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, typescript-typings

I am trying to add Android platform to the Ionic 2 project but getting below issue.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'internal/util/types'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
at evalmachine.<anonymous>:44:31
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:11:8)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
```

Below are my ionic 2 project information:

```
   Cordova CLI: 4.2.0
   Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
   Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
   Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
   ios-deploy version: Not installed
   ios-sim version: Not installed
   OS: Windows 8.1
   Node Version: v10.15.2
   Xcode version: Not installed
   npm version: 6.9.0
```

Any idea? what i am missing

Answer (score 1):

What caused the problem for me was that I upgraded node and needed to rebuild my project.

```
npm rebuild
```

Fixed it for me.

Comment: might be it is because you are using a beta version of ionic 2,

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling and installing NodeJS again. That might help you to resolve this issue.